# Scroll within a XamRichTextEditor

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, infragistics, xamrichtexteditor

I have a `XamRichTextEditor` control that displays a potentially long text. I can place the caret to an arbitrary position and I can set any custom selection (from `Start` to `End`). All works fine. But these operations do not automatically scroll. Thus, if I set the caret (or a selection) to a location that is currently outside the view of the control (because above or below the text that is currently visible), the caret (or selection) is simply not visible (because outside the view).

So, my simple question is:

How can I scroll to the current caret position or the current selection (or any location) within a XamRichTextEditor?

It's hard to believe that this obvious use case was not considered by Infragistics.

Comment: why -1 and why close vote?

Comment: Usually the `BringIntoView()` method is used to make a required part of a document to be visible. Unfortunately, the Infragistics examples don't demonstrate how it is possible to get the `FrameworkContentElement` object from the `XamRichTextEditor.Selection` or the `XamRichTextEditor.Caret`. And `yes` - the Infragistics library has lot of gaps.

Comment: Thanks @Jackdaw. I tried long to find any `FrameworkContetElement` from within the XamRichTextEditor I could apply the BringIntoView method, but I didn't find one. Currently, I am trying to use the `XamRichTextEditor.VerticalOffset` property and the carets Y-offset, but I am still trying.